# Sort array by unique id, by keeping last in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make unique `id` list from an array that has multiple same id's. But I want it to keep the last one, not the first one. The code I have here keeps first unique object. Is there an `Array.findLastIndex()` I can use here. I searched but couldn't find a similar question.

```
[{id:2,name:'first'}, {id:2,name:'second'}, {id:3}]
    .filter((v, i, a) => a.findIndex((t) => (t.id === v.id)) === i)
```

That code returns :

```
[{id: 2, name: "first"}, {id: 3}]
```

But I want:

```
[{id: 2, name: "second"}, {id: 3}]
```

I have wrote the next one which gives me the result, but ideally I do not want to copy and reverse my array twice, it will be quite inefficient for long arrays.

```
[{id:2,name:'first'}, {id:2,name:'second'}, {id:3}]
  .slice().reverse()
  .filter((v, i, a) => a.findIndex((t) => (t.id === v.id)) === i)
  .reverse()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store them in a `Map` id => object, and pull the values back out:

```js
arr = [{id:2,name:'first'},{id:2,name:'second'},{id:3}]

result = [...new Map(arr.map(x => [x.id, x])).values()]

console.log(result)
```

Since the `Map` constructor overwrites existing values, you automagically get the last one.

As noted in the comments, after this, the result elements will be ordered by the *first* occurrence, not by the last:

```js
arr = [
   {id:3,name:'first 3'},
   {id:2,name:'first 2'},
   {id:2,name:'second 2'},
   {id:3,name:'second 3'}]

result = [...new Map(arr.map(x => [x.id, x])).values()]

console.log(result)
```

If you additionally want to *sort* by id, as your title suggests, then add

```
.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
```

to the above.

Comment: this approach could change the order, because of the insertation order.

Comment: @NinaScholz: right, added a note about that. It's unclear to me which order the OP is after.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to generate an object using the `id` property as the keys while overwriting previous values. Then you can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) on the generated object:

```js
let arr = [
  {id:2, name:'first'},
  {id:2, name:'second'},
  {id:3}
];

let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, obj) => (acc[obj.id] = obj, acc), {}));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reverse the array and take the first found uniqe value. After filtering reverse the result set.

```js
var array = [{ id: 2, name: 'first' }, { id: 2, name: 'second' }, { id: 3 }],
    unique = array
        .reverse()
        .filter((s => ({ id }) => !s.has(id) && s.add(id))(new Set))
        .reverse();

console.log(unique);
```

A classic approach.

```js
var array = [{ id: 2, name: 'first' }, { id: 2, name: 'second' }, { id: 3 }],
    seen = Object.create(null),
    unique = array.reduceRight((r, o) => {
        if (!seen[o.id]) {
            r.unshift(o);
            seen[o.id] = true;
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: Is that an iife inside filter?

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth, right, it takes a set for keeping track of seen `id`.

Answer (score 0):

I like Shidersz answer the most, but here's another possibility:

```js
    let arr = [
      {id:2, name:'first'},
      {id:2, name:'second'},
      {id:3}
    ];

    let res = arr.filter((v, i) => {
      for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (v.id === arr[j].id) return false
      }
      return true;
    })
    console.log(res);
```

My guess is that it uses less memory (doesn't have to create an intermediate object) but it probably runs slower due to not using constant time to look for duplicates. Not by much though, since the  lookup is quite scope between current value and next first duplicate.